# How to create a button with rubber or jelly kind animation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to create a button with animation like "When I press on any point of button, it should look like I pressed a rubber or jelly and after few a while, it come to its own earlier position by own".

I had searched every possible place, but i didn't get what i need.
If any one had did this earlier or have a suggestion on it, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have two different images for the button. One without the jelly effect, another with. Create the Method touchDown to set the button's image to be the jelly one, then the method touchUpInside to set it back to the original (alongside anything else pressing the button does).